# Back4App - Parse Class level permission for limited number of users

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, back4app

Is this possible to set a list of users for a class that can get or set new data. Only that list will be available to work with this class.

Let's say you are super admin or premium user and I would like to deny any request from other list which are not in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do that using Roles: https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#roles

You can create a Role called Admin (for example), add the admin users to this Role, and set the class CLP to only allow read/write from this Role.